# I want to get the count of records in specific time periods from one table group by one column

Tags: sql-server

This is the query i use:

```
select  
 (select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '07:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '09:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '09:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '11:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '11:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '13:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '13:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '15:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '15:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '17:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '17:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '19:30:00.000' group by lid)  
,(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) > '19:30:00.000' group by lid)
```

but i get this error : 
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when ....

Comment: you need 4 spaces at the start of each line of code to get correct formatting (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: you are getting more than one row.. this i think can only mean you have more than one `lid` in `_Trans` are you missing a where clause? e.g. : `(select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' AND lid=5)` - the group by is not required if you are only looking at rows for one lid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tired running one of those sub queries on their own?

`select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' group by lid`

its telling you exactly what this issue is: you cannot take more than one row and put it in a cell..

This would work if you want to see only one lid at time - just add a where clause:

```
`select COUNT(Id) from _Trans where cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' and lid =  5`
```

Would you like this query to show more than one row (as in maybe a row for each lid?). if so you would need a different approach.. e.g somehting like:

```
select  
    coalesce(a.lid,b.lid) as lid
    "before 730"
    ,"before 930"
FROM
    (select 
        lid
        , COUNT(Id) as "before 730" 
    from 
        _Trans 
    where 
        cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' 
    group by 
        lid)  as a
full outer join 
    (select 
        lid
        , COUNT(Id) as "before 930"  
    from 
        _Trans 
    where cast(TDate as time) > '07:30:00.000' 
        and cast(TDate as time) < '09:30:00.000' 
    group by 
    lid) as b
on a.lid = b.lid

    **and so on for other metrics**
```

Its probably best to get all your lids up front like this.. (but please also consider Dheerendras approach as its probably a safer way to do it thought the output format is different. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47073831/359135)

```
select  
    a.lid
    ,"before 730"
    ,"before 930"
    ,"before 1130"

FROM
    (select distinct 
        lid
    from 
        _Trans 
    )  as a
left outer join 
(select 
        lid
        , COUNT(Id) as "before 730" 
    from 
        _Trans 
    where 
        cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' 
    group by 
        lid)  as b
 on a.lid = b.lid
 left outer join
    (select 
        lid
        , COUNT(Id) as "before 930"  
    from 
        _Trans 
    where cast(TDate as time) > '07:30:00.000' 
        and cast(TDate as time) < '09:30:00.000' 
    group by 
    lid) as c
on a.lid = c.lid
left outer join
    (select 
        lid
        ,COUNT(Id) as "before 1130"
    from 
        _Trans 
    where 
        cast(TDate as time) > '09:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '11:30:00.000' 
    group by 
        lid) as d
on a.lid = d.lid
```

Comment: I think the last query you wrote is doing the job, i am now testing it out , i think the problem was that i had some "LId"s in one time period that do not exists in another , so the number of rows on each time period is different , with coalesce those rows will be shown as null,thank you so much

Comment: Now how can i extend your query for more time periods ?

Comment: I have added one more sub query, hopefully you can se the pattern. i have also added a table at the start of the from clause that gets all the lids so that you can keep joining to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the below code

`;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT ID,lid, CASE WHEN cast(TDate as time) < '07:30:00.000' THEN 'Block1'
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '07:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '09:30:00.000' THEN 'Block2'
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '09:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '11:30:00.000' THEN 'Block3'
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '11:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '13:30:00.000' THEN 'Block4' 
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '13:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '15:30:00.000' THEN 'Block5' 
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '15:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '17:30:00.000' THEN 'Block6' 
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '17:30:00.000' and cast(TDate as time) < '19:30:00.000' THEN 'Block7' 
                   WHEN cast(TDate as time) > '19:30:00.000' THEN 'Block6'

              END AS TimeFrame
    FROM _Trans
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowsCount
       ,TimeFrame
       ,lid
FROM CTE
GROUP BY TimeFrame,lid`

Comment: This eliminates subqueries and usage of cte allows the processing in memory.

Comment: But i need the "LId" column in results , this query is only showing the number of records in each time period ( if i remove "group by"s from my sub queries it will show your query results in 8 columns  ) , but that is not grouped by LId column

Comment: thanks for your edit , but i want the time periods in columns , this query gives the combination of LId , TimePeriods and count(*) in rows , however gordatron`s last update is doing the job , thanks again